# How to merge items in a list, based on the first two characters of the next item in the list

Tags: python, list

I have this code, which is inspired by others, which is now succesfully merging items starting with '##' with the previous item in the list. However I have weird behaviour, where the last item is disappearing.

List:

```
tokens = ['Hello', 'this', 'is', 'a', 's', '##e', '##ntenc', '##e']
```

Checking if something is a subtoken (which has ##)

```
def is_subtoken(string):
    if string[:2] == "##":
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Merging the tokens

```
merged_text = []
for i in range(len(tokens)):
    if not is_subtoken(tokens[i]) and (i+1)<len(tokens) and is_subtoken(tokens[i+1]):
        merged_text.append(tokens[i] + tokens[i+1][2:])
        if (i+2)<len(tokens) and is_subtoken(tokens[i+2]):
            merged_text[-1] = merged_text[-1] + tokens[i+2][2:]
    elif not is_subtoken(tokens[i]):
        merged_text.append(tokens[i])

print(merged_text)
```

This is the output:

```
['Hello', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'sentenc']
```

Whereas was expected:

```
['Hello', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence']
```

I can't get my head around it. Is there something missing needed to merge a multitude of these '##' items?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could just use join, replace, and split pretty easily:

```
'|'.join(tokens).replace('|##', '').split('|')
```

edit: you're missing the last element because you never add it unless it's *not* a token

Comment: Very simple & it worked amazingly. Thank you!

Comment: When there is `"|"` in original string, that's will make some mistakes.

Comment: yeah, you can use whatever delimiter you want, e.g. `delim = 37 * '|+-'` should probably not be in any string.

Answer (score 1):

Your processing seems more complex than it needs to be.

```py
merged = []
for token in tokens:
    if token.startswith('##') and merged:
        merged[-1] += token[2:]
    else:
        merged.append(token)
```